# Adding multiple layers to leaflet map in Shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, polygon

I am having trouble adding different layers in my shiny app. I want to add a group of polygons along with a group of circle markers along with a group of arbitrary (.png) icons. I have the group of geojson files that are added in a for loop that is wrapped in an observe({}) statement with the function 
map$addGeoJSON(x) where x is a feature with coordinates. The 'map' object is created by the command

```
map <- createLeafletMap(session, 'map')
```

This is all fine and dandy, and the polygons get added fine. I also want to commit to this way of adding the polygons. That should not have to change.

The error happens when I try to add markers onto that map object in the same way (e.g. with map$addMarkers(....) ) Below is the error and the code for the app that tries to add markers in the desired way and fails.
The shiny app below with the quakes data recreates my error

```
"Listening on ...
Warning: Error in observerFunc: attempt to apply non-function
Stack trace (innermost first):
    56: observerFunc [C:/Users/jbz/Desktop/leaflet-map-question.R#35]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer"

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletMap("map", width = "100%", height = "100%",
             options=list(center = c(40.736, -73.99), zoom = 14)),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                sliderInput("range", "Magnitudes", min(quakes$mag), max(quakes$mag),
                            value = range(quakes$mag), step = 0.1
                ),
                selectInput("colors", "Color Scheme",
                            rownames(subset(brewer.pal.info, category %in% c("seq", "div")))
                ),
                checkboxInput("legend", "Show legend", TRUE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filteredData <- reactive({
    quakes[quakes$mag >= input$range[1] & quakes$mag <= input$range[2],]
  })

  colorpal <- reactive({
    colorNumeric(input$colors, quakes$mag)
  })


  map <- createLeafletMap(session, 'map')

  observe({
    df <- filteredData()
    map$addMarkers(
      lng=df$Lon, lat=df$Lat, popup = paste(as.character(df$mag)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

(How) can I add markers correctly while insisting on using the function createLeafletMap()?

```
map <- createLeafletMap(session, 'map')
```

Comment: Can you also supply your `createLeafletMap()` function too?

Comment: `createLeafletMap` is deprecated

Comment: case mistake : `lng=df$lon, lat=df$lat`

Comment: Trying to replicate the structure as on https://rpubs.com/Sylvie/cityBikeApp

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filteredData()
leafletProxy("map") %>%
addMarkers(df, lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat, popup = paste(as.character(df$mag) )
```

under `observe`

Comment: OP states : "(How) can I add markers correctly while insisting on using the function createLeafletMap()?" - Is your answer : No?

Comment: map is still created using `createLeafletMap()`.  `renderLeaflet` would be different.

Comment: Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'metaData' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Comment: Getting same error as HubertL. Error in UseMethod("doResolveFormula") : 
  no applicable method for 'doResolveFormula' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Comment: same error here. I think an `if(!is.null(x)){do something}` is needed somewhere